# perform perm.lmer test across multiple channels (including random effects)

Tags: r, permutation, lmertest

I have a large dataset with EEG data where I have several columns: channel (58), subject (24), condition (3), trial_nb (with the number of each trial), and then I have individual columns for each data point from -200 to 1100ms where I have the data of each amplitude voltage. Data looks like this (with an example of 1 of my 3 conditions called Congr, and 2 out of the 58 channels) :

---

| channel | subject | condition | trial_nb | -200 | -199 | -198 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| AF3 | 01 | Congr | 1 | -2.817600 | -3.068800 | -3.256800 | ... |
| AF4 | 01 | Congr | 1 | 1.679700 | 1.628300 | 1.582800 | ... |
| ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... | ... |

I want to run a permutations test implementing linear mixed models. The function in R is perm.lmer ().
The example given in the package website is the following:

```
(Fz ~ Deviant * Session + (Deviant * Session | Subject),
data=MMN[MMN$Time > 150 & MMN$Time < 250,])
```

Nevertheless, this only applies to one of the channels in the data, called Fz and I want to run it over all the electrodes.
I was able to run a permu.test based on the example given in the package that looks like this:

```
perms <- permu.test(cbind(AF3, AF4, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, CP1, CP2, CP3, CP4, CP5, CP6, CPz, Cz, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4, FC5, FC6,FCz, FP1, FP2, FPz, Fz, M1, M2, O1, O2, Oz, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, PO3, PO4, PO7, PO8, POz, Pz, T7, T8, TP7, TP8) ~ condition | time, data=df_perm_)
```

I tried to do merge both permutation examples to do the perm.lmer but it does not work. I wrote this:

```
perms <- perm.lmer(cbind(AF3, AF4, C1, C2, C3, C4, C5, C6, CP1, CP2, CP3, CP4, CP5, CP6, CPz, Cz, F1, F2, F3, F4, F5, F6, F7, F8, FC1, FC2, FC3, FC4, FC5, FC6, FCz, FP1, FP2, FPz, Fz, M1, M2, O1, O2, Oz, P1, P2, P3, P4, P5, P6, P7, P8, PO3, PO4, PO7, PO8, POz, Pz, T7, T8, TP7, TP8) ~ condition + (condition | subject) | time, data=df_perm_).
```

The error that I get is:

> Error: Must subset rows with a valid subscript vector. i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input. x Input has size 3800 but subscript `ix` has size 0.

I think that the problem is that I do not know how to include the subjects in the loop to create a df for the permutations for which I convert the df into a format longer.

I hope I explained my problem correctly! Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `perm.lmer` is not in base R and is not in `lme4`.  Can you tell us where/what package you got it from?

Comment: ... looks like it's in the `permutes` package ... ?? (`sos::findFn("perm.lmer")`)